# Very odd spam from user "true"

Tags: discussion, spam

The user [true](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/1018/true?tab=stats) has one point of rep and one answer on a question about [games for uncompetitive groups](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2855/what-are-great-gamer-games-that-are-still-great-for-uncompetitive-groups/2859#2859). The original post seemed like a totally reasonable answer but embedded within it was a link to a commercial website apropos of absolutely nothing (it's since been edited to remove the offending link). The user's name matched part of the web address, which makes it seem like the account is fraudulent (as opposed to the answer being hacked).

Is this sort of thing relatively common-place? Other than editing the answer to remove the inappropriate link are there other actions that should be taken against the user account (perhaps for now just wait and see as it's only one offense).

Answer (score 5):

This was the original source of the post:

> Shadows over Camelot or Pandemic and Agricola, [true religion jeans][1] the game comes with rules for a family version, which is much easier to pick up than the full game.
>
> [1]: http: //www. true religion jeans discounted .com

This human-driven spam is coming from a chinese IP and posted similar things across many sites in the network. Usually it's text copy-pasted from another answer in the same question, this text actually appears unique, oddly enough.

Anyway, we deleted this user and banned the entire `1.2.*.*` IP range this came from.

Comment: That's such a crazy amount of effort to go through to post a link that got deleted in a couple of hours. So weird.

Comment: you banned a /16 network? wow

Answer (score 1):

Just because it only gets one or two views doesn't seem to stop spammers from spamming a variety of sites.

Until the collective political will comes around to make it an international crime (or to isolate national networks and make it a national crime), various groups will continue to pay people to post spam.

Someone is paying the jerks to continue to post adverts. Until that stops, expect more to come.

**As for action:** SE has a flag mechanism. Sufficiently reputable users may flag particular posts as spam. When enough flags accrue, the post automatically disappears. Further, the leaders of a given SE site can zap offensive posts, as well.